# run specific role on any condition

Tags: ansible

I have created a role named `cleanup` which is my final role in playbook (which handles some cleanups after running all otherroles)

here is a simplified version of my playbook

```
- hosts: myhost
  roles:
    - common
    - postgresql
    - rabbitmq
    - web
    - cleanup
```

the problem is if playbook fails ansible doesn't run clean role, how can I mark that specific role as important, so ansible would run it even all other roles in playbook has failed?

Answer (score 2):

Ansible has ignore_errors feature for tasks. But your case about whole role. I think you can seperate roles two chapters in a playbook file. Thats tricky but efficient.

```
- hosts: myhost
  roles:
    - common
    - rabbitmq

- hosts: myhost
  roles:
    - cleanup
```

So if you raise any fail on first chapter playbook will keep continue on next chapter :)

Also ! Ansible 2.0 has new block mechanism, thats not what exactly you want but maybe you think re-design your logic mechanism.

```
tasks:
 block:
  - debug: msg='i execute normally'
  - command: /bin/false
  - debug: msg='i never execute, cause ERROR'
 rescue:
  - debug: msg='I caught an error'
  - command: /bin/false
  - debug: msg='I also never execute :-('
 always:
  - debug: msg="this always executes"
```

[Ansible Blocks](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/0208a2cb308e3b6ba4e3f009acf2e2b46e76471f/docsite/rst/playbooks_blocks.rst)